# -std default value for GCC4.8.1

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

If I don’t specify the `-std` option when compiling my C++ app using GCC4.8.1,
does it apply c++11 value by default?

I read the words from GCC document, but still not sure of that. My English is not good, so it might be my bad.

> -fext-numeric-literals (C++ and Objective-C++ only) Accept imaginary, fixed-point, or machine-defined literal number suffixes as GNU
>   extensions. When this option is turned off these suffixes are treated
>   as C++11 user-defined literal numeric suffixes. This is on by default
>   for all pre-C++11 dialects and all GNU dialects: -std=c++98,
>   -std=gnu++98, -std=gnu++11, -std=gnu++1y. This option is off by default for ISO C++11 onwards (-std=c++11, ...).

Comment: That's not the section that tells you what the default is. Look for a section with a title something like "Standards". (I'd check it belt, but I don't have access at the moment.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update in 2018: in the newest version of gcc, the default option for `-std` is now `-std=gnu++14`.

---

From [gcc standards](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) 2.2 C++ language

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu++98.

So if you want to enable C++11 features, you have to add the option `-std=c++11` or  `-std=gnu++11` (for C++11 with GNU extensions)

Comment: @DeanChen Well, you only tagged your question with C++. If you are interested in C, I'll add it in the answer in a moment.

Comment: That's a mistake, I am only into C++ here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the man-page:

> ```
>        c++98
>        c++03
>            The 1998 ISO C++ standard plus the 2003 technical corrigendum and some additional
>            defect reports. Same as -ansi for C++ code.
>
>        gnu++98
>        gnu++03
>            GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code.
> ```

Just if somebody wonders what happend to C++03.